# Utilizing admin panel values elsewhere in a module

Tags: 7, users

So I've got a custom admin panel page in a module I've written, and I want to get a value out of it.

Let's say I have a text box on this admin page, with a value, and I want to get that at some other point.

Do I need to use variable_set and put that into the database and then variable_get it in the function I want to use it in - or do I call it some other way?

Basically this thread:

https://drupal.org/node/2074589

Essentially, I just want to have a user be able to select a picklist value in the admin, and then call that picklist value later on in the actual module, for display.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize [`system_settings_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) when you write your admin form.

```
function mymodule_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['my_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text',
    '#title' => 'Title',
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['my_textfield']) ? $form_state['values']['my_textfield'] : '',
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Submitting this form will call [`system_settings_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form_submit/7) which saves all the form fields as a variable, so you need to be careful when naming the form fields.

Now all you need to do is call:

`variable_get('my_textfield', 'default value to return if no value is set');`

from any function after drupal is bootstrapped.

Here's more information on how to create a configuration form: [Creating the configuration form](https://drupal.org/node/1111260)

Comment: Is the second argument optional?

Comment: for `variable_get`? Second argument is optional, as it defaults to `NULL`. See [`variable_get`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)